# SWI-Prolog - calling predicate using data from json api call

Tags: swi-prolog

I am trying to add an api to someone else's SWI-Prolog application so that I can call it via AJAX from an PHP/JS application that I'm writing. Other than the API, I don't need to alter the existing SWI-Prolog application itself but, with a background in PHP and JS frameworks, I'm finding it a very steep learning curve. If I had time, I'd love to learn Prolog from the ground-up but I'm hoping SO can provide a short-cut so I can concentrate on the app that will call the api. I have come across a very useful tutorial: http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/ which suggests that the following is the sort of thing I should be doing:

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_json)).

% the following allows more lenient content-types in request
:- multifile http_json/1.

http_json:json_type('application/x-javascript').
http_json:json_type('text/javascript').
http_json:json_type('text/x-javascript').
http_json:json_type('text/x-json').

% server(Port) starts webserver on specified Port
server(Port) :- http_server(http_dispatch, [port(Port)]).

% call handle_api on requests to /api/mark
:- http_handler('/api/mark', handle_api, []).

handle_api(Request) :-
        http_read_json_dict(Request, Query),
        solve(Query, Solution),
        reply_json_dict(Solution).
```

However, in my case, instead of 'solve(Query, Solution)' I need to call a predicate as follows:

```
mark(question(q_no, q_part, q_sub_part), answer_string)
```

The (probably very basic) things that I can't work out are:

1. How can I do the equivalent of console.log() or print_r in SWI-Prolog so that I can see e.g what http_read_json_dict returns, to help me understand:
2. What form of JSON do I need to pass in as 'Query' to get something that I can then work with to extract 'q_no', 'q_part', 'q_sub_part', 'answer_string' which I can then pass into my mark/2 and question/3 predicates.

Any help/pointers very gratefully received.